# multi-gpu inference tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wanted to perform multi-gpu inference using tensorflow/Keras

this is my prediction

```
 model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

 # Load weights trained on MS-COCO
 model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

 # COCO Class names
 # Index of the class in the list is its ID. For example, to get ID of
 # the teddy bear class, use: class_names.index('teddy bear')
 class_names = ['BG', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
                'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
                'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
                'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
                'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
                'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
                'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
                'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
                'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
                'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
                'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
                'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
                'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
                'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
                'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']


 # Load a random image from the images folder
 file_names = next(os.walk(IMAGE_DIR))[2]
 image = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, random.choice(file_names)))

 # Run detection
 results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)

 # Visualize results
 r = results[0]
```

Is there a way to run this model on multiple gpus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the GPU_COUNT as per the number of GPUs in the system and pass the new `config` when creating the model using `modellib.MaskRCNN`.

```
class InferenceConfig(coco.CocoConfig):
    GPU_COUNT = 1 # increase the GPU count based on number of GPUs
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

config = InferenceConfig()
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)
```

https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/demo.ipynb

Comment: hey when i try to run with two gpus it works fine, but with 4 gpus it gives InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 600 values, but the requested shape has 4800
   [[{{node tower_0_4/mask_rcnn/mrcnn_detection/Reshape_1}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](tower_0_4/mask_rcnn/mrcnn_detection/packed, tower_0_4/mask_rcnn/mrcnn_detection/Reshape_1/shape)]]  any ideas?Thanks

Comment: When we set `GPU_COUNT = 2` and  `IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1` - how it works exactly? Are the two models perform combined as one GPU and inference on one image or model or data get split during inference time and rejoin back?